# Email for Username, Phone Number for Password. Bad Idea?

Tags: authentication, passwords

Neither will be public.

I want a really minimal user registration, that gets people the most connected to my site.

Can you think of pros or cons to this?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. How bad the idea is will depend on the context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: why not use google or facebook authentication?

Comment: Bad idea.  At the very least, allow a user to set their password.  (Also, make sure you *hash* the password immediately upon receiving it.  It should *never* be recoverable.)  If you want to make registration even easier, use OAuth and whatnot to allow users to register without even needing to set a password.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like it. A person's email address can be guessed (usually firstname.lastname at something), and their phone number can be looked up by name using a reverse lookup 411 website.

Usernames and passwords should not be correlated at all with any third value. In your case, if I guess that someone belongs to your site and guess their email address (or search for it online), then I am one lookup away from possibly having their password.

Comment: I didn't know about the reverse 411 lookup. That could be a pretty easy hack.